# View all transaction logs in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is anyone familiar if there are and updates on this topic in SQL Server 2014? Is MS going to finally document the transaction log or provide its own tool for this?

I’ve seen this post that provides some details on SQL Server 2008:

[View all transaction logs in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210010/view-all-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008)

I’ve looked at datasheets and documentation on [MS website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/sql-server-2014.aspx) but I couldn’t find anything.

Is anyone familiar if there are better ways to do this? I have SQL Server 2014 CTP 1 installed but maybe I missed this option somehow…

Reason I’m asking is that we historically had a lot of issues with accidental updates and deletes such as wrong WHERE statement or WHERE statement completely missing.

Comment: The fix for "accidental updates and deletes such as wrong WHERE statement or WHERE statement completely missing." isn't to scour some log in the hope of recovering the data - it's taking away permissions of those users who shouldn't be running ad-hoc SQL on the production databases.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - You are absolutely correct on this. We disabled access to some users but we want to make sure we have this in case someone with DBA privileges makes an accidental mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know your only options for this are:

- Third party tool  [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) (Red Gate has a free tool but only for SQL Server 2000)
- Undocumented commands such as DBCC LOG or fn_dblog.
- Change data capture – this is SQL Server feature that automatically creates history tables but its only available in enterprise edition

We are also evaluating SQL Server 2014 CTP 1 for it’s in memory features but I haven’t been able to find anything on this topic. I don’t really believe MS is going to allow this any time sooner. Right now their focus is on enterprise level features such as high availability, in memory queries and such… Also, they have their own version of this in CDC.